# Windows scheduled task - .bat runs forever

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-tasks, cmd.exe

I've a scheduled task to clean up folders on a hard drive automatically; it removes files older than a certain amount of days.

Basically it runs a `.bat` file  full of lines that looks like this:

```
FORFILES /P "D:\Folder1\SubFolder1" /D -30 /C "cmd /c del /F /Q @path"
FORFILES /P "D:\Folder1\SubFolder4" /D -30 /C "cmd /c del /F /Q @path"
```

I've noticed that the task often never ends; and I don't know why. The `.bat` file ends in a couple of minutes when run manually and the folders are cleaned up afterwards.

I guess the reason might be that sometimes a prompt may appear:

> Delete [...] are you sure? (Y/N): _

because of recursive deletion in subfolders. Notice I added `/F` and `/Q` switches to the `del` command.

How can I make sure that the task automatically answers `Y` to any prompt that may appear? Or is this not the path I should take to solve my problem - should I improve my `.bat` file?

Comment: Can you get the script to log stdout and stderr to a log file.

Comment: @richard Good idea to add that to the task. I will monitor these files in the coming weeks and let you know the result.

Comment: how about: *(forfiles /d -30 /c "cmd /c del /q @file") && (forfiles /d -30 /c "cmd /c rd /q /s @file")* ?

Comment: @MAKZ No, the directory tree itself must be kept at all times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that forfiles finds both files and directories, and you are only looking to delete files.

Please try this in the /C command:

"cmd /c if @isdir==FALSE del @path"

This will only fire the del command if the forfiles iterator does NOT point to a directory.

I would leave out the -q, at least for now, to see if this goes ok. But I think you shouldn't need/want to muzzle confirmation questions if you target the right things.

Also, the /f is only required if you want to delete read-only files. Only force if you are sure it's necessary :)

Good luck, hope this helps.

Comment: That is probably an improvement for my `.bat`, thank you for that, but how would you explain that it runs fine like it is and it doesn't give errors about trying to `del` a folder?

Comment: In any case, I removed both `/F` and `/Q` switches and included your `if @isdir==FALSE` check everywhere. The task runned fine but there aren't many files in the folders now. I'll report back if it fails in the near future.

Comment: It didn't give "error-questions" because of the /q switch suppressing them. Now it doesn't give errors because it doesn't run into them.
Why it actually got stuck sometimes, I don't know.